# Percentage Change VBA changing array

Tags: excel, vba

While the percentage difference works when i run it line by line in debug mode, I experience runtime error 91 after it calculates 10 out of the possible 44 separate sheets Attached are the 2 screenshots for reference [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MFOi.png) & [EndResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onFEE.png).

I'm trying to speed up the code and make sure it runs without any hiccups. If I try to get rid of the activate and select functions to make it run faster, how would I proceed ahead? Thanks in advance for guidance. 
EDIT: The range is not dynamic, as every month, a new month column with data will be auto-inserted. Also, I've attached that code as well.

```
Sub PercentageCalc()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = False

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

pos = Sheets(i).Index
Sheets(pos).Activate
With ActiveSheet

If Len(Sheets(i).Name) < 5 Then


dcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Columns(dcol).Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Columns(dcol + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Columns(dcol).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


Cells.Find(What:="year", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-2]/RC[-12])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
ActiveCell.Offset(5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-2]/RC[-12])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))


Cells.Find(What:="month", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-3]/RC[-4])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, 
ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
ActiveCell.Offset(5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-3]/RC[-4])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, 
ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

dcolvar = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells.Find(What:="qtr", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If dcolvar Like "2" Or dcolvar Like "4" Or dcolvar Like "7" Or dcolvar Like "10" Then
    Cells.Find(What:="qtr", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-4]/RC[-5])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
ActiveCell.Offset(5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-4]/RC[-5])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

Else

If dcolvar Like "3" Or dcolvar Like "5" Or dcolvar Like "8" Or dcolvar Like "11" Then
Cells.Find(What:="qtr", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-4]/RC[-6])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
ActiveCell.Offset(5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-4]/RC[-6])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

Else

Cells.Find(What:="qtr", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-4]/RC[-7])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
ActiveCell.Offset(5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-4]/RC[-7])-1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

              End If            

           End If

      End If

End If

End With

Next i

Exit Sub

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of activesheet use `Sheets(pos).` So, you would have `With Sheets(pos)` and then code in the with like so `.range("a1").value="xyz"`

Comment: The code you have posted cannot run.  Please update the code with that which you are actually using.

Comment: @freeflow I just updated the code

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'd have specified a range, but it's not dynamic. Every month, a new column is inserted, which moves the variance % column to the right.

Comment: That was just an example, so you would use with as discussed in my comment, but your `Columns(dcol + 1).Select` would then be `Columns(dcol + 1).Select` for example

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  If you are `Inserting a column` and `Moving your calculations to the right`, it might be simpler to do this with a Table.  If you use structured references for your formulas, adding a column at the right end of the table would automatically move the formulas one column to the right, and you wouldn't need to change the formulas at all, ***since they are referring to the same table row on which the formulas lie***.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : I'll be doing just that as it seems the easiest. I could definitely go with trying out (For Each) statement with Select Case, and move with new sheets(pos). I'll get back here once I rework it out.